# Connection Refused for Apache 2.4 Virtual Host

Tags: mac-osx, virtualhost

I have Apache 2.4 running on Mac OS X. `apachectl configtest` give me: Syntax OK.

I have two virtual hosts set up, one called localhost, one called test.dev.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/psychomachine/Development/_localhost"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/psychomachine/Development/test"
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias www.test.dev
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

localhost just works:

```
↪ curl -I -L localhost                                                                                                                                                              15:51:08
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 14:51:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 08:52:04 GMT
ETag: "c-5265f1673f500"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/html
```

whereas test.dev doesn't:

```
↪ curl -I -L test.dev                                                                                                                                                               15:51:01
curl: (7) Failed to connect to test.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

My hosts file has an entry for test.dev, which is why I can ping test.dev and hear back from 127.0.0.1.

```
↪ ping test.dev                                                                                                                                                                     15:53:39
PING test.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
^C
--- test.dev ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.069/0.092/0.111/0.017 ms
```

I've spent hours looking at this, but I still don't understand how it is possible to ping test.dev but still get connection refused. Apache is listening on port 80, and I am not getting a page forbidden kind of error. There is nothing in Apache logs for test.dev, because the request for test.dev never makes it to Apache.

I am missing a crucial element of the puzzle — and I hope somebody will be able to point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
As I said, Apache is listening on 80:

```
sudo lsof -i ':80'                                                                                                                                                                16:54:46
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   2464   root    5u  IPv6 0x8883a2a43af0ca7f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2466 daemon    5u  IPv6 0x8883a2a43af0ca7f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2467 daemon    5u  IPv6 0x8883a2a43af0ca7f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2468 daemon    5u  IPv6 0x8883a2a43af0ca7f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2469 daemon    5u  IPv6 0x8883a2a43af0ca7f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2470 daemon    5u  IPv6 0x8883a2a43af0ca7f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

**Additional info**

```
scutil -r test.dev                                                    08:25:59
Reachable 

telnet test.dev                                                       08:26:17
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

telnet test.dev 80                                                    08:26:43
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

`127.0.0.1 test.dev` is in `/etc/hosts` and `Listen *:80` is in apache's conf.

Comment: Please `ping localhost` and post the output. It should obviously output IP 127.0.0.1, but just to be sure.

Comment: It does. `PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.076/0.090/0.105/0.014 ms`

Comment: Are you getting any warnings when restarting Apache through the CLI? Have you checked the logs for any suspicious warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though Apache was listening to port 80, this port was refusing connection.   In the end this is what worked for me:

I made sure port 80 was open for TCP on all interfaces, which on OSX you do by adding

```
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 80
```

to `/etc/pf.conf`. Reloading pfctl didn't quite do the trick, but a reboot did. Now all my virtual hosts are accessible. And the world is in order again.

Answer (score 8):

Check you `httpd.conf` to see if you have the following:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

You have to replace it with:

```
Listen *:80
```

By doing this, Apache will bind to all of the computer's interfaces, not just the *loopback* interface.

Don't forget to restart Apache after editing `httpd.conf`.

Comment: thanks, but that's exactly it —  I do have *:80 in httpd.conf.

Comment: old answer, but relevant for me after updating macOS from Catalina to Big Sur... not sure what happened there but !

Comment: Relevant also for me on Win10

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect test.dev with another available port fot http or https communication. OR stop  the previous PID with port ':80' and then run.
Check the process ID with -

netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'

kill -9

Comment: thanks, but killing processes or changing the port doesn't make a difference.

Comment: may be you cannot access two different processes with same port.

Comment: try with another and tell me what excatly you want to do

Comment: ok. i had apache listen to :80 only. after adding listen 8080 in httpd.conf (so that apache listens to both 80 and 8080) and changing vhosts.conf for test.dev to listen to 8080, i could access localhost on 80 and test.dev on 8080. but my goal is to access both virtual hosts on 80.